# Assign IPAddress in NetworkSettings Docker Container

Tags: docker

I'm now trying to run docker container and want to set ip static for that container. What i've done so far:

1. Run docker network set subnet
2. Run docker container, set network set ip using --ip="172.20.0.3" as example
3. Check docker container using docker inspect and find IPAddress is not setup yet or return `""`
4. Docker inspect return IPAddress on Networks was assign successfully
5. Docker inspect also return IPAddress on NetworkSettings was not assign

To describe IPAddress is not set please find detail of docker inspect below:

> ```
>      "NetworkSettings": {
>         "Bridge": "",
>         "SandboxID": "cc37c6777a8f65268ab088bc6587f463aee7c7878d1fa6045229e4c6ca9b8055",
>         "HairpinMode": false,
>         "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
>         "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
>         "Ports": {
>             "3306/tcp": [
>                 {
>                     "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
>                     "HostPort": "3306"
>                 }
>             ]
>         },
>         "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/cc37c6777a8f",
>         "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
>         "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
>         "EndpointID": "",
>         "Gateway": "",
>         "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
>         "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
>         "IPAddress": "", //HERE IPAddress that i want to set
>         "IPPrefixLen": 0,
>         "IPv6Gateway": "",
>         "MacAddress": "",
>         "Networks": {
>             "my-netto": {
>                 "IPAMConfig": {
>                     "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.3"
>                 },
>                 "Links": null,
>                 "Aliases": [
>                     "5b909fdca063"
>                 ],
>                 "NetworkID": "6697e2deabb509d0f4a207674909d19c552bb8b77d1c62bdc94b6979b1844f10",
>                 "EndpointID": "fd902fcf7351a777b90c7eed4c27a7255fa84aa9f705db84db226dd42c554faf",
>                 "Gateway": "172.20.0.1",
>                 "IPAddress": "172.20.0.3",
>                 "IPPrefixLen": 16,
>                 "IPv6Gateway": "",
>                 "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
>                 "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
>                 "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:03",
>                 "DriverOpts": null
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> ]

Any command for set IPAddress in NetworkSettings section?

Any help would be appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You first have to create network using this command

```
docker network create --subnet=172.28.0.0/16 --ip-range=172.28.5.0/24 --gateway=172.28.5.254 name-of-network
```

Than start container using this command :

```
docker run -it --name $container_name -d -h "$host_name" -p $host_port:8080 --ip="172.20.5.2" --mac-address="12:34:56:78:9a:bd" --network="name-of-network" $image-name
```

you can start multiple container using above command by just changing `--ip` and `--mac-address`

Hope this will help.

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you @chitan thakar, i have tried but still `""` in IPAddress.

Comment: is your container running ?? can share output of `docker ps -a` mention name of your container here.

Comment: `56c41aa6208d        mysql                         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   1 second ago        Up 5 seconds             0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp             mysqldb_testip`

@chintan thakar

Here is my `docker ps -a` output for container that i already set

Answer (score 1):

Since editing IPAddress is not allowed in container i find work around using --link and it works like a charm.

In my case, i want to deploy a mysql container and deploy another Node.js apps. After several articles, i found this [docker mysql documentation](https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/mysql/#start-a-mysql-server-instance) is preparing some cases that if you want to use mysql as connection to another apps.

So when I run my docker apps, i add `--link mysql-docker-name:mysql` in run command and in database configuration put `mysql` as a host.

Hope this will help you guys who had a same problem.